# A quick doubt on a Calculus problem involving inflection points

Tags: calculus

A problem asks to show whether the following is true or false:

> If the graph of $f$ is concave upward in $(a,c)$ and concave downward
>   in $(c,b)$, where $a<c<b$, then $f$ has a point on inflection at
>   $x=c$.

I am pretty sure the statement is true, but how can I show it mathematically? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If $f$ continuous?

Comment: If you know that $f$ is twice differentiable, then you can show that $f''$, the second derivative, must have a zero in c.

Comment: Maybe try double differentiation, then show that $f^{\prime\prime}$ is positive just before $c$, negative just after $c$, and $0$ at $c$. I know this probably seems stupidly obvious, but maybe that's all the question wants. Regardless, you would still need to invoke the definition of a point of inflection for your proof to be truly rigorous.

Comment: That's one common definition of an inflection point. What (other) definition are you using?

Comment: The definition we've been using for a point of inflection is where $f''=0$

Comment: @daniels That assumes that $f$ is twice differentiable, which is an assumption that you should edit into the question. See the other comments that addess that case.

Comment: @user56478 That's exactly what I want to show (that $f''=0$ at $c$). It is very intuitive to me, but I'm not sure how to go about showing it.

Comment: @daniels That's a terrible definition of inflection point, which unfortunately some calculus texts do use.  See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) for the more usual definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x} \,$.  Note $x=0$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$.

Now, first derivative is $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2}$ and second derivative is $f''(x) = -\dfrac{2}{x^3}$. Take $a=-1$, $c=0$, and $b=1$. All the conditions for the assumptions you state hold, but $c=0$ is not an inflection point because it is not in the domain.

Comment: By the way, what if we assume $f$ is continuous? Then I suppose that would be true, right? How would you show it? (Please let me know if I need to open another topic for this). Thank you very much.

Comment: @daniels: As some of the comments under the original question point out, it depends on the precise definition of the inflection point you are using. For example, one of your comments mention $f''=0$. Just requiring $f$ being continuous would not be enough for this. Consider $x^{4/3}$ for which the second derivative will be undefined at $x=0$. ... (cont'd: 1 of 2 comments)

Comment: ... (cont'd 2 of 2 comments) According to Wikipedia, "inflection points are the points of the curve where the curvature changes its sign while a tangent exists". If we go with that definition, consider $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ which is continuous, but $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3} x^{-2/3}$ is undefined at $x=0$ (so tangent doesn't exist at $x=0$) but with $f''(x)=-\frac{2}{9 \, x^{5/3}}$ switches signs to the left and the right of $x=0$. Since tangent doesnt exist, according to the Wikipedia definition, $x=0$ is not an inflection point. By the way, $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ has what's called a "cusp" at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the function $f $ defined by

$f (x)=\sqrt {x} \;\; $if$ \; 0 \leq x <1$ and
$f (x)=-\sqrt {-x}  \;\;$if $\;-1 <x \leq 0$

it is not differentiable at $x=0$.

but
$$\forall x\in (0,1)  \;\; f''(x)<0$$ and

$$\forall x\in (-1,0)\;\; f''(x)>0$$

Comment: $x=0$ still *is* an inflection point, so I am not sure what is the point that you mean to drive.

Comment: Not necessarily. The usual definition of an inflection point is one where the function changes concavity, see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Definition) or [mathworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Definition). The function is not required to be differentiable at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Usually an [inflection  point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Definition) of a curve is defined as a point  where the concavity changes its sign and where there exists a tangent line.

With this definition we can have functions that change concavity at a point that is not an inflection point because we have not a tangent at this point, as :
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \quad for\quad  x\le 0  \\ \sqrt{x} \quad for\quad  x>0 
\end {cases}$$

But, if the function is twice differentiable at the point $c$ we are sure that a tangent  exists at this point , so it is a true inflection point.